# maven-assembly-plugin include *.properties at root level of zip

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to get maven to include my `*.properties` files when it zips up my artifacts. They are located inside `src/main/resources`. I tried adding the `fileSet` element to my assembly file, but the resources are not being included in the zip. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602365/maven-how-to-include-specific-folder-or-file-when-assemblying-project-depending) which seems to indicate that adding `fileSet` should work.

plugins.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly>
    <id>release</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
    </fileSets> 
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties that you want to include inside your ZIP are located in the `src/main/resources` source directory of your project. So the `<fileSet>` element should point to this directory.

`${project.build.directory}` is Maven current build directory, which is by default `target`. You could also point to the temporary directory where Maven copies all resources during the build but it is preferable to stick with the permanent data where possible.

As such, you just need to change your `<fileSet>` element with:

```xml
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work without specifying `<fileSet>` though?

Comment: @krasnaya Because you need to tell the plugin which file to look for. It isn't like the maven-jar-plugin that will package resources into the main jar by default. maven-assembly-plugin was designed to be more flexible so you need to configure it properly.